# Confused about try...except in vb

Tags: database, vb.net, try-catch

I'm working on a project that allows a user to search a leader board database by name. I was encouraged to use a try...except statement to stop an error if the database doesn't contain the name, but I am not familiar with how to use it so I've run into an issue. Please could I have assistance in where I've gone wrong and how to rectify it? I'd like for the record to show for the name searched, or for no record to appear if the name isn't present.

```
    Imports System.Data.OleDb
    Public Class FrmAllResults
        Dim CtnConnection As OleDbConnection
        Dim DsDataset As New DataSet()
        Dim StrConnectionString As String = vbNull
        Dim StrSql As String
    Private Sub FrmAllResults_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            StrConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=..\..\..\DbIteration2Database.mdb"
            StrSql = "select * from Leaderboard"
            CtnConnection = New OleDbConnection(StrConnectionString)
            CtnConnection.Open()
            Dim AdptOleDbAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(StrSql, CtnConnection)
            AdptOleDbAdapter.Fill(DsDataset)
            AdptOleDbAdapter.Dispose()
            LblAllResults.Text = DsDataset.Tables(0).ToString
        End Sub
        Private Sub BtnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSearch.Click
            Dim StrNameSearched As String = TxtName.Text
            Dim StrLeaderboardEntry As String
            Try
                StrLeaderboardEntry = (DsDataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(StrNameSearched).ToString)
            Catch ex As Exception
                StrLeaderboardEntry = vbNull
            End Try
            LblAllResults.Text = StrLeaderboardEntry
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably confused about it because this is the wrong use of exception handling.  (And whoever encouraged you to do this has misled you.)  Exceptions are for unexpected errors in the code.

For example, if the code is unable to connect to the database at all then it may generate an exception, and the application should be able to recover from that exception.  Finding no matching record in the data is not an exception.  It's not an error.  It's just a simple "no results found" situation.

The problem is that the code *assumes* results are found, and is artificially generating an error as a result here:

```
StrLeaderboardEntry = (DsDataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(StrNameSearched).ToString)
```

If no records are found then `Rows` will be empty, so this will result in an error because the code *assumes* that `Rows` *can never* be empty.  That assumption is incorrect, so change the assumption.  For example:

```
If DsDataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
    StrLeaderboardEntry = (DsDataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(StrNameSearched).ToString)
Else
    ' No records were found.  Notify the user in some way.
End If
```

This finds another good example of an exception.  If the query succeeds then I'd at least expect `Tables` to always have an element, so that assumption is much safer and if it's false then truly something unexpected (an exception) is occurring.  But `Rows` could certainly be empty under normal conditions in a search, so the code should expect and handle that.

As a general piece of advice, never use a `Try/Catch` for something that can be handled with an `If/Else`.